# Predefined set of variations in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have 3 formats of products with variations:

| Format 1: | Format 2: | Format 3: |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1kg cake price is $20 | 1kg cake price is $30 | 1kg cake price is $80 |
| 2kg cake price is $30 | 2kg cake price is $60 | 2kg cake price is $120 |
| 3kg cake price is $40 | 3kg cake price is $80 | 3kg cake price is $160 |
| 4kg cake price is $60 | 4kg cake price is $100 | 4kg cake price is $190 |
| 5kg cake price is $70 | 5kg cake price is $110 | 5kg cake price is $240 |

Question:

I want to have these variations saved and I need choose 'Format 1' or 'Format 2' wherever I want in WooCommerce products, I don't want to add same prices every time I add product, I just want to choose format and it should populate a list of variations saved in 'Format'

Comment: Woocommerce plugin "Advanced product variation" could be useful: https://woocommerce.com/document/advanced-product-variation/

Comment: @GrafiCode thanks for sharing, it won't fulfill my requirements. but I got an idea after seeing this pluign, I will look for a pluign which will at least allow me to add variations on category based. then I will add my 'formats' as category :)